# How can I make my browser to go on a site every X seconds?

Tags: tampermonkey

So, I simply need a script for Tampermonkey to go to a specific site every x seconds on the same tab no matter what website or addon is open in the browser.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        arga
// @description arga
// @include     *
// ==/UserScript==

function view() {
setTimeout(function() {

window.location.replace("https://www.google.com/");

}, 250000);
};
```

I expect that this script goes to google.com every 250 seconds, no matter what extension page or website is opend but it doesn't.

Comment: Delete the `function view() {` and the `};` lines. Then it will work better.

Answer (score 0):

Per Brock Adam's comment:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        arga
// @description arga

// ==/UserScript==

setTimeout(function() {

window.location.replace(“https://www.google.com/“);

}, 250000);
```

Your script *defines* a function, but doesn't call it.

To call the function you defined, you would do this:

```
(function view () {
  // your code here
})();
```

Which is effectively the same as:

```
function view () {
  // your code here
}

view();
```